# Display raster data in folium (handling no data values).

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster, folium

I am trying to display a raster-type data (numpy array) using folium. This is what I have so far.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import ImageOverlay
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

z = np.random.rand(100, 100)
m = folium.Map([30, -80], zoom_start=6, tiles='stamentoner')
folium.plugins.ImageOverlay(
    image=z,
    name='sample map',
    opacity=1,
    bounds=[[25, -75.], [35., -85.]],
    interactive=False,
    cross_origin=False,
    zindex=1,
    colormap=cm.viridis
).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save('sample.html')
```

What I want to do now is to assign no-color to certain values of z; e.g. z < 0.9. I tried:

```
z = np.where(z < 0.9, np.nan, z)
```

But it did not work. nan cells still have color.

Comment: The colormap uses a speficic color for bad values. Did you try cm.viridis.set_bad(alpha=0)`?

Comment: Thanks. It did not work. It works when using plt.imshow to display z, but no success with folium.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best way to do this but I have a solution to this without having to save it as PNG first.

I assume you have a NumPy array with some values. For my case this array is `img`, it's a 2D array with seven distinct values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -128]`. It's a categorical raster map so I use qualitative colors.

Here is how I add the raster layer:

```py
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(img, 
                                  opacity=1, 
                                  bounds = bounds,
                                  colormap=lambda x: raster_to_coloridx[x]).add_to(m)
```

Now the key here is (as stated in the docs of folium) that `colormap` argument can also take RGBA values. The A of RGBA is the alpha of the color, in human terms it is the opacity. Simply if you set the alpha of any color to 0, you'll get a transparent color, which is what you're looking for.

My case is easier since I'm using qualitative colors, all I have to do is to define the dictionary `raster_to_coloridx[x]` smartly. Here is how I do it:

```py
{0: (0.8941176470588236, 0.10196078431372549, 0.10980392156862745, 1.0),
 1: (0.21568627450980393, 0.49411764705882355, 0.7215686274509804, 1.0),
 2: (0.30196078431372547, 0.6862745098039216, 0.2901960784313726, 1.0),
 3: (0.596078431372549, 0.3058823529411765, 0.6392156862745098, 1.0),
 4: (1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0),
 5: (0.6509803921568628, 0.33725490196078434, 0.1568627450980392, 1.0),
 -128: (1, 1, 1, 0)}
```

Obviously, -128 is the filling value and while others get 1.0 for their alpha, that gets 0. What you can do is, instead of passing a cmap, pass a function that is almost a cmap with a twist:

```py
import matplotlib.cm as cm
def get_color(x):
    decimals = 2
    x = np.around(x, decimals=decimals)
    ls = np.linspace(0,1,10**decimals+1)
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return cm.get_cmap('viridis')(ls)[np.argwhere(ls==x)]
    elif x==-128:
        return (0, 0, 0, 0)
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

This functions takes a value between 0 and 1 (that means you have to normalize your raster array first), rounds it up to `decimals` decimals, then finds the corresponding value in the `viridis` colormap and returns it as an RGBA array. If the value is `-128` which is the fill value, return (0,0,0,0) which is a transparent color. Otherwise it raises and error.

### What's next?

You only have to update your function as follows (note argument `colormap`):

```py
folium.plugins.ImageOverlay(
    image=z,
    name='sample map',
    opacity=1,
    bounds=[[25, -75.], [35., -85.]],
    interactive=False,
    cross_origin=False,
    zindex=1,
    colormap=lambda x: get_color(x)
).add_to(m)
```

### Improvements

If this works slow, it's because for each pixel the function is called it will recreate the colormap. You can possibly avoid this using a decorator or partial function from `functools`. The same can also be used for parametrizing the decimal and/or the colormap. I hope this helps!

Comment: @D_Serg....I think the above solution you mentioned is for a single band image. I want to know if I have a multiband image and I want to plot a RGB image onto the folium map then what changes needs to be done in your above code....

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to transform values you want to be masked to 0 ( or other nodata value) before import to leaflet.
Set this value to nodata in raster.
Save image to PNG.
Then you import to leaflet.